# Download files from nexus repository

Tags: maven

How to download files from nexus server ? (Is it for only Maven plugins repository or We can store any dependencies of my project)

Answer (score 4):

You can use maven plugin :

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:get -DreadmoteRepositories=http://nexus.mydomain.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots -Dartifact=com.mydomain.myproject:myproject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar -Ddest=myfile.jar
```

OR, you can use REST API if you want : https://maven.java.net/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/rest.artifact.maven.redirect.html

Answer (score 0):

nexus per artifact has multiple files (metadata, pom.xml, source, javadoc, jar, etc..), you can download them and use separately in your own project, but that doesn't sounds like very good idea when you have maven todo this for you in managed way